# Firefox does not fill data-src

Tags: angularjs, firefox

I'm using `AngularJS` to fill in a `data-src` attribute in an `img` tag:

```
<img src="/img/lazyload.gif" data-src="{{product.image}}" alt="{{product.alt}}" class="ng-lazy-load">
```

In firefox this results in:

```
<img src="{{product.image}}" data-src="{{product.image}}" alt="the correct Alt tag" class="ng-lazy-load">
```

In Chrome and IE this works as expected:

```
<img src="/img/image.png" data-src="/img/image.png" alt="the correct Alt tag" class="ng-lazy-load">
```

So in Firefox, the `alt` attribute is filled in correctly by `AngularJS` but the `data-src` attribute isn't. I tried changing the `data-src` to `data-source` and then the result is as expected, but the lazy load library we use `JQuery Unveil` does not support renaming attributes.

Does anyone have suggestion how to work around this issue?

Note to self: Make a bug report to `AngularJS`.

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you try, progressively, with: firstly, `ngSrc` instead of `src`; secondly, `ngAttrDataSrc` instead of `dataSrc`; thirdly, with AngularJS 1.3.0-beta.14 or later?

Comment: I upgraded to 1.2.20 (from 1.2.16, we need IE8 support) and that broke Chrome! Then I tried `ngAttrDataSrc`, and it fixed Chrome and works for Firefox too. Thanks man! If you post this as answer I'll accept it.

Comment: can you please comment the code, how you have used it.

Comment: `<img src="{{product.image}}" ng-attr-data-src="{{product.image}}" alt="the correct Alt tag" class="ng-lazy-load">`